# PyMuPDF get optimal font size given a rectangle

Tags: python, pymupdf

I am making an algorithm that performs certain edits to a PDF using the fitz module of PyMuPDF, more precisely inside widgets. The font size 0 has a weird behaviour, not fitting in the widget, so I thought of calculating the distance myself.
But searching how to do so only led me to innate/library functions in other programming languages.
Is there a way in PyMuPDF to get the optimal/maximal font size given a rectangle, the text and the font?

Comment: You might be able to use the [insert_textbox](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shape.html#Shape.insert_textbox) method, for instance by doing a binary search on different fontsizes until you find the largest one that fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Seon wrote, there is `rc = page.insert_textbox()`, which does nothing if the text does not fit. This is indicated by a negative float `rc` - the rectangle height deficite.

If positive however, the text **has** been written and it is too late for optimizing the font size.

You can of course create a `Font` object for your font and check text length beforehand using `tl = font.text_length(text, fontsize=fs)`. Dividing `tl / rect.width` gives you an ***approximate*** number of lines in the rectangle, which you can compare with the rectangle height: `rect.height / (fs * factor)` in turn is a good estimate for the number of available lines in the rect.

The fontsize `fs` alone does not take the actual **line height** into account: the "natural" line height of a font is computed using its ascender and decender values `lh = (font.ascender - font.descender) * fs`. So the above computation should better be `rect.height / lh` for the number of fitting lines.

`.insert_textbox()` has a `lineheight` parameter: a factor overriding the default `(font.ascender - font.descender)`.

Decent visual appearances can usually be achieved by setting `lineheight=1.2`.

To get a good fit for your text to fit in a rectangle **in one line**, choose `fs = rect.width / font.text_length(text, fontsize=1)` for the fontsize.

All this however is no guarantee for how a specific PDF viewer will react WRT text **form fields**. They have their own idea about necessary text borders, so you will need some experimenting.